# C++, CEF - how to embed a Browser in windows mode in an application

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

[image]

I'm trying to embed a browser into my application in the windows mode, which is similar to the attached image. However, **I can only load a webpage in the fullscreen mode without any button** like a normal browser.

**My code is as follow:**

**Load URL function:**

TestCefBrowser::GetCefBrowser ( )->GetMainFrame ( )->LoadURL ( CefString ( url ) );

**Create browser function:**

CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowser ( g_CefWindowInfo, TestCefBrowser::GetTestCefBrowser ( ).get ( ), CefString ( url ), g_CefBrowserSettings, nullptr, nullptr );

**How can I embed a complete browser as the image using the CEF framework?**
(I'm using the C++ programming language)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There's the great example [cefclient](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/master/tests/cefclient/). You can find there all what you need.